# What is the best approach to create Application Settings in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I shared the variables globally in `AppServiceProvider` for settings like this in boot function

```
$app = Setting::find(1);
view()->share('app', $app);
```

But the problem with this is when i run `php artisan migrate` it throws errors then i comment out these lines and run the command then it works. If there is any best approach share it .

**PS :** My app settings is saved in database. Settings include application name, logo, description and other fields.

Comment: What is the error that you get from `php artisan migrate`? And do you get the same error also when you run any other `php artisan` command?